# C# namespace mechanism in Javascript

Tags: javascript, module, namespaces, modularity

I'm new to javascript in a way of doing more with the language than fetching data via AJAX on a button click using jQuery.

Coming from a C# background I do not see a direct approach of using namespaces in Javascript. I tried to mimic it using the following code. My question is concerned to the `using(namespace);` method which copies all from the namespace object to the window object. I have not encountered such coding while searching how to deal with javascript in a modular fashion and I would like to know the folliwing: 1) Does this pattern have a name? 2) What are the pros and cons to the `using(namespace);`?

```js
console.clear();

var System = {
  IO: {
OutletOption: {
  Console: 1,
  MessageBox: 2
},
Outlet: function Outlet(outletOption) {

  var _self = this;
  var _outletOption = outletOption;

  //private
  _self.log = function(txt) {
    console.log(txt);
  };
  _self.messageBox = function(txt) {
    alert(txt);
  };

  //public
  _self.out = function(txt) {
    switch (_outletOption) {
      case System.IO.OutletOption.MessageBox:
        _self.messageBox(txt);
        break;
      case System.IO.OutletOption.Console:
        _self.log(txt);
        break;
    }
  };

  return {
    out: _self.out
  };
}
  }
};

function using(namespace, scope) {
  console.log(scope);
  for (var key in namespace) {
scope[key] = namespace[key];
  }
}

(function() {
  function execute() {
  
//All your code goes here
using(System.IO, this);
var o = new this.Outlet(this.OutletOption.Console);
o.out("Some test text.");

  };
  return {
execute: execute
  };
})().execute();
```

Comment: I suggest you to use a framework like Angularjs in order to have a better approach modularity-wise.

Comment: Your `using()` function pollutes the global *namespace* and could very likely lead to conflicts, which is kind of what namespaces are supposed to prevent to begin with. You can sort of simulate namespaces by using nested objects and Javascript used to have a `with` keyword that set an implicit namespace, but it was deprecated because it had all sorts of issues of its own.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Good point that it pollutes! Thanks.

Comment: @PhiceDev I have to dive in Angularjs then. Is there something within knockoutjs that matches what you are pointing me to within Angularjs? The reason I am asking is because I have worked with knockoutjs and it didn't come to my attention that it takes care of modularity within Javascript.

Comment: In principle knockoutjs is a different framework, probably you can obtain the same results, I'm not familair with it, hereby a link for a quick comparison among the two frameworks. https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/engineering/angularjs-vs-knockout-js-vs-vue-js-vs-backbone-js-which-framework-suits-your-project-best/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have namespaces. If you come from C# you would find easier using TypeScript and maybe Angular2+. TypeScript is JavaScript with types.

Comment: Thank you for your addition. I have considered TypeScript. What holds me back to use it is the required type definitions: External libraries may not have them or are quickly outdated. I must say, that your answer isn't really of an answer to me, more a comment as it doesn't answer to two questions I asked.

Comment: I've already said that JavaScript does not have namespaces :)